# How can I deal with "URI is not registered" in Manifest file created by Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-manifest

I have just created a new project in Android Studio.  The only thing I have done so far is to add two extra menu items by editing the `main_menu.xml` and `strings.xml` files.  However I am getting this error in `AndroidManifest.xml`

[image]

I have tried closing down Android Studio and then reopening it.  I have also tried both Clean and Rebuild Project.  None of these have helped.  I have looked in **Settings->Language & Frameworks->Schemas and DTDs** as suggested to find that the **External Schemas and DTDs** section is empty.

Additionally I have followed the `Fetch external resource` link which reports:

**"Error while fetching http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"**

What else could be the cause of this issue?

Comment: Is this error shown in console? From your screenshot everything looks fine.

Comment: When I hover over the schema declaration I get the error shown in the screenshot.  When I try to build the project I get the same error in the console.  If it were fine, it wouldn't  be in red...